# Why does a child div with a fixed width, let the margin expand to the borders of the parent

Tags: html, css

**Remark**

I am absolutely sure that these questions have been asked before, but I just cannot seem to find it. Whether I am searching with the wrong keywords or just not understanding what is going on I do not know. Honestly, I am quite embarrassed to even be asking this question since it seems absolutely trivial. It has been quite some time that I worked with CSS, so I am quite sure that this is something really basic.

**Questions**

1. Why does a child div that is smaller (e.g. with a fixed with) have a right margin that extends up until the border of the parent element?
2. Why am I not able to restrict said margin with specifying `right-margin`?
3. What is the best way to resolve this?

**Example**

```html
<div>
  <div style="height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: black" />
</div>
```

As you can see in the inspector, the most nested `div` actually has a margin that extends all the way to the parents border.

[image: Inspector]

Setting the `right-margin` does not affect this.

Any help would be deeply appreciated, please do feel free to redirect me to other questions if this has already been asked!

Comment: Could you perhaps create a codesnippet and share it here so I can inspect the matter?

Comment: @KayAngevare will do! I need to jump into a meeting, but will do it straight afterwards!!!

Comment: @Kay: while I appreciate that you're asking for information to help OP posting that code *here* - in the question - is required, ideally as a [working code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/82548), linking to code elsewhere is a bonus, but certainly not a replacement for posting code *here*.

Comment: @DavidThomas clear and polite message, thank you for editing the question and adding the snippet... "sir".    :)

Comment: @Fluous what you're actually seeing is not the margin of the block itself, but the space the browser has calculated to be used by the block. The 'space' takes up the entire line because the element has received the `display` value of `block`. Which makes the element take up the entire row it is placed on.

Comment: Thank you @KayAngevare! This helps a lot with understanding why things are the way the are!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because by default div is a `block(display: block)` which as you probably already know forces a container to take 100% width

For its child to be position at the start it needs right margin which in this case is `calc(100% - 50px)`, this pushes element to left to place it at the same offsetX as its parent.

You cannot restrict it unless you change `display: block` of parent to `flex`, `grid` or whatever it is, because this is not your thing.

Well theoritically you can restrict it but you have to add `margin-left` to child instead of trying to restrict `margin-right`.

Comment: Or.. alternatively, give the div a `display:inline-block` property.

Comment: Yes correct, that also works. All in all, somehow default output settings have to be changed. There are a lot of ways.

Answer (score 1):

just add `display:inline-block` on style code.

```
<div>
 <div style="height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: black; display: inline-block" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the browser's own space. You can try reset css.

Example:

```
    html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ol, ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```